# return more than one elements with XQuery:invalid expression

Tags: xml, xquery, zorba

I use zorba as XQuery processor. I am trying to figure out how to return more than one elements with XQuery. Then I found [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/712184?start=0&tstart=0).

xml doc:

```
<data>
<person>
<name>Me</name>
<last>Proj</last>
<mrn>54</mrn>
<phone>43434</phone>
<fax>34343</fax>
</person>
<person>
<name>Me2</name>
<last>Proj</last>
<mrn>542</mrn>
<phone>434342</phone>
<fax>343432</fax>
</person>
</data>
```

xqy doc:

```
let $last :="Proj"
return
<html>
<head><title>Example</title></head>
<body>
<table frame="box">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Last</td>
<td>MRN</td>
</tr>
{
for $person in ( doc("test.xml")/data/person\[last=$last\] )
return
<tr>
<td>{$person/name/string()}</td>
<td>{$person/last/string()}</td>
<td>{$person/mrn/string()}</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

command line:

```
$ zorba -i -f -q test.xqy
test.xqy>:13,45: static error [err:XPST0003]: invalid expression: syntax error: unexpected character "\"; raised at /tmp/zorba20151126-72875-uij83f/zorba-3.0/src/compiler/api/compiler_api.cpp:252
```

I am pretty new to XQuery. Could someone point out how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zorba is complaining about this expression in your `for` clause:

```
doc("test.xml")/data/person\[last=$last\]
```

The backslashes are not valid XQuery or XPath; removing them will leave you a valid expression:

```
doc("test.xml")/data/person[last=$last]
```

**Update**: here's a breakdown of the expression:

- `doc("test.xml")` is a function invocation: it retrieves a document at the given URI (http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_doc.html)
- `/data` is an XPath step; it selects all the `<data/>` elements that are immediate children of the *context* node (in this case, the document)
- `/person` is another XPath step; it selects all the `<person/>` elements that are immediate children of the *context* node (in this case, each of the previously selected `<data/>` elements)
- `[last=$last]` is an XPath predicate; it filters the *context* node (in this case, each of the previously selected `<person/>` elements) by testing if the node matches the predicate

To further deconstruct the XPath steps `/data` and `/person`:

- `/` is shorthand for the `child::` axis; the expanded form of `/data` is `/child::data`
- there are many other XPath axes. A commonly used axis is `//`, which expands to `descendant-or-self::`
- Here's more details on XPath axes: https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/xpath-axes-and-their-shortcuts/

To further deconstruct the predicate `[last=$last]`:

- the brackets signify the beginning and end of the predicate
- `last` selects the `<last/>` elements that are immediate children of the *context* node (in this case, the previously selected `<person/>` elements)
- `=` is the set equivalence operator; it evaluates to `true` if any atom in the left-hand sequence is present in the right-hand sequence
- `$last` is a variable bound at the beginning of your XQuery expression (`let $last := "Proj"`)

In summary, the predicate `[last=$last]` will evaluate to `true` for any `<person/>` element that contains a `<last/>` element with a string value equal to `"Proj"`.

Comment: May I ask an extra question? what is that [last=$last]? what do Square brackets mean here?

Comment: I've added some more detailed notes on the expression.